# django doesn't detect migrations

Tags: django, migration, database-migration, django-south, django-cms

I am using modeltranslation(https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) and django-eav(https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) apps. I want to translate django-eav app model's field `description`. As it is documented, i created class:

```
class AttributeTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
        fields = ('description', )
```

and registered it: `translator.register(Attribute, AttributeTranslationOptions)`. Basically this creates additional fields for languages that my project supports, in my case it's 4. It should be: `description_en`, `description_ru` and so on.. This works fine with my other models, but when i try to translate Attribute class, it says **(1054, "Unknown column 'eav_attribute.description_en' in 'field list'")**. Then i try to migrate, but it doesn't detect changes. Tried south schemamigration app_name --auto, also doesn't work.

How can i solve this? 
Thanks

**EDITED:**

Tried python manage.py schemamigration eav --initial. Now it finds these fields:

```
+ Added field description_ru on eav.Attribute
 + Added field description_lv on eav.Attribute
 + Added field description_en on eav.Attribute
```

BUT, then another error occurs: **FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE `eav_enumvalue` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `icon` varchar(300) NULL)
The error was: (1050, "Table 'eav_enumvalue' already exists")**

Comment: Where have you put the `translation.py`?

Comment: What version of django are you using? You shouldn't ever need to reference south directly in the supported versions

Comment: I have `translation.py` file in my app folder. It works good with other models. Django version 1.6.11

Comment: Okey i solved it but still have a problem. I called `schemamigration eav --initial`, then commented `fields = ( 'description', )` in translation.py file and then migrated normally. Then had an error "Can't DROP 'description_lv'; check that column/key exists". Tried migrate eav 0004 --fake, it worked. Uncommented that field again and ran normal migration and it worked. Now can i remove 0003 initial migrate file? Because i have 0001 initial migrate, so it won't ruin anything?